# Associating authenticated user to form object Djano

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am having troubles passing a User(a foreign key) into a submitted form.
Here is what the model looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from person.models import UserProfile
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import signals


User = get_user_model()
# Create your models here.


class UserPost(models.Model, Activity):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userpostauthor')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    postvideo = models.FileField(upload_to='UserPost/postvideo', blank=True, null=True)
    postPicture = models.FileField(upload_to='UserPost/postpicture', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here's my views.py form:

```
class TimelineView(CreateView):
    fields= ['content', 'postvideo', 'postPicture']
    model = UserPost
    success_url = reverse_lazy('timeline_feed')
    template_name = 'main/timeline.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user

        return super(TimelineView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, form=None):
        context = super(TimelineView, self).get_context_data()
```

I would get this error when I try to submit the form:

> IntegrityError at /timeline/ null value in column "author_id" violates
> not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (20, , , ,
> 2020-07-14 20:43:53.631628+00, null). Request Method: POST Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/timeline/ Django Version: 2.2.12 Exception
> Type: IntegrityError Exception Value:  null value in column
> "author_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains
> (20, , , , 2020-07-14 20:43:53.631628+00, null).

Obviously I am doing something wrong. What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: It should be `form.instance.author = self.request.user`. Right now you simply make a Django attribute that does not map on a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the field is `author`, not <s>`user`</s>, so you set this with:

```
class TimelineView(CreateView):
    fields= ['content', 'postvideo', 'postPicture']
    model = UserPost
    success_url = reverse_lazy('timeline_feed')
    template_name = 'main/timeline.html'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).